# jQuery datepicker maxDate auto onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

Good day,

I have a datepicker and I set the selection limit to 5 days before today.
Here is my example code:

```
$(function() {

    var from_date = $(':input[name="dailyCommand.fromDate"]');
    var endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 5);

    from_date.prop('readonly',true).datepicker({maxDate: endDate});

})
```

For example, let say today is 3 March 2016.
The datepicker is working find, but just the last day will auto focus, here is my screen shot:
[image]

Image 1 is the datepicker when I click on the text box. From the picture, you can see that the 5th days before today (27th Feb 2016), is displaying color like `mouseover`, but actually not, I am not pointing my mouse on 27th, I am just click on the datepicker text box.

However, in Image 2, I move my mouse to any day in the picker, the 27th color will display like others, because the 'mouseover' color already on other day. And then I move away my mouse away from the date picker, whole thing display correctly now.

My question is how to fix the 27th color to same as color when I first click on the datepicker text box.

Same thing happen when I tried to simulate in w3c website, the 27th is look like `onmouseover`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var from_date = $(':input[name="dafromDate"]');
    var endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 5);

    from_date.prop('readonly',true).datepicker({maxDate: endDate});

})
</script>

<input type="text" name="dafromDate" maxlength="20"/>
<p><b>Note:</b> type="date" is not supported in Internet Explorer.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please give your code in fiddle link

Comment: @Muthupandianc I not sure how to give my code in fiddle link. But I have put my sample code, you can copy it and try in W3C website.

Comment: which browser you used for this issue? In my system this working fine in firefox browser.

Comment: @Muthupandianc, I tried in my firefox version 43.0.1. It has the same problem also, do u copy my code and try in W3C website? In W3C website, the 27th day will show like onmouseover also.

Comment: yes i seen that, i thick this issue in jqueryui.js. see this demo http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range  in jqueryui.com. you can see same issue in that demo